# How much RAM should I put aside for ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I currently have windows 8 in my laptop with 4 gb RAM.. I recently installed the virtual machine of ubuntu. Now I need to run a tool whose memory requirements are as follows : 1) Atleast 5 gb RAM 2) Atleast 20 gb hard disk space

And this tool can be run only on ubuntu. Now how do I meet this set of requirements? By what amount should I extend my RAM and how much of RAM and hard disk should be put aside for the virtual machine?

Comment: 1. "my laptop with 4 gb RAM", 2. "memory requirements are as follows : 1) Atleast 5 gb RAM" ... are your sure ?

Comment: yes pretty sure :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, lets break this down to what you need and what you have:-

Your base OS (Win 8) requires **2gb** of RAM to function (assuming you're using x64), if you lower it down to this level then it will run, but it will run slow.

Ubuntu requires **512mb** of RAM to function, so taking **512mb** is going to be a minimum. Ubuntu also needs **5gb** of disk space to install.

The obvious solution is to split the ram 50/50 and give each OS **2gb**, this is enough for both of them to function, but your programs requirements are **5gb**, so you may still have trouble even when giving as much as possible to Ubuntu.

As far as disk space is concerned, calculate what you need in total (**5gb+20gb**) then add another **1/3** on top of it for spurious log files and other unforeseen applications, so you're looking at about **35gb** of hard disc space.

Overall, I don't think your laptop is suitable for running the application you're trying to run due to the sheer lack of RAM available.